# Cannot render with gpu in all Blender version now

Tags: rendering, gpu

After I moved my blender addon folder (may be because of this), if I change to rendermode, cannot render anything or Blender just shuts down.

Was using 3.4, but 2.7 version works only with cpu.

I also downloaded 3.5  but it may bring preference from 3.4, just crashing right away when I change to rendermode too.

Next day I need to work with Blender for client work. Its very crucial, but dont know why suddenly not working.

---

im using
GPU:
x5 of NVIDIA 3090TI(4 of them is founder edition version,  1 is ZOTAC version) very recently I added ZOTAC version  but same 3090ti.

CPU:  ryzen threadripper 5995wx

RAM: 256gb

harddisk also has sufficient area.

also  every another renderers are works well(3dcoat,unreal,houdini,keyshot,substance )

Comment: assuming that you have opened Edit :: Preferences :: System :: Cycles Render Devices (and a choice other then "None"), have latest NVIDIA driver installed; in Render Properties (Tab) you can select GPU Compute?  Or is that grayed out?    Don't answer with a comment below mine: Edit your question to add this info.